# Changing package name of hibernate managed entities

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

After doing some refactoring moving some classes into different packages, I started seeing following error while querying the database with criteria builder:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [in.helpi.ironlegion.db.hibernate.entity.UserEntity@1863fc] did not match expected type [in.helpi.ironlegion.cerebro.db.hibernate.entity.UserEntity
```

If I change the package name back to in.helpi.ironlegion.cerebro.db.hibernate.entity it works just fine.

**Update**
I am able to properly fetch Individual entities. But when I go for querying entities having reference to other entity I get this error. For example:

```
public class CommunityAccessEntity extends BaseEnity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserEntity_id")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
...
}
```

If I query it on user using criteria builder like:

```
 query.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(CommunityAccessEntity_.userEntity), user)));
```

I get the above error.

Has somebody also faced similar issues..

Answer (score 1):

You must have implemented Serializable interface in your entity classes as it is one of the thumb rules of entity class.

Java serialization is tightly coupled with class name and package name. Your data is stored in database with your old package entity. Now you changed the package name and system will not be able to find the records in DB with your new package. This is why when you restore the package, it works.

If you are using xml based configuration for hbm, please check hbm files whether new package have been updated in all the places.

Comment: Yes I am using Serializable interface. But why I am able to properly fetch the old entities from the database and only when I go for querying  it gives me type mismatch exception? I am using annotation based setup and my persistence file has correct package names for entities.

Comment: @akshay202, please check your hbm files whether new package is updated in all the places.

Comment: I dont have hbm files, I am using annotation based approach.

Comment: You said, _I am able to properly fetch the old entities from the database_, How are you fetching the data as your query is not working?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question.